# Migration to create table which is already present in database

Tags: ruby, migration

I have created psql table through psql console. I have created a model in rails for the corresponding table. Now if I want to write a migration to create a table so that someone using my code doesn't need to create a table through psq console, and also it should not remove table for me when running the migration. How to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your migration file:

```
create_table :foo do
  .....
end unless table_exists? :foo
```

[`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#table_exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-table_exists-3F).

Answer (score 2):

In case you are reading this answer, and you are on Rails 6, a new flag was added to `#create_table` in [Rails 6 beta1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-600beta1-january-18-2019) to address this exact problem.

**Example:**

```
create_table :posts, if_not_exists: true do |t|
  t.string :title
end
```

Comment: I think you might remove _“beta 1”_; the flag was added in _Rails v6_ :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails encourages developers to modify their database only through migration files. Because when you do manual changes, `schema.rb` is not updated. This will make other developers schema inconsistent with yours.

If you have created a table in your local database manually, you can drop the table  manually and create a new migration file. Then if you run the migration file, it will create the table and update `schema.rb` accordingly.

If you still want to write the migration only for the other developers, you can create a migration with the create table and then comment it while running the migration. `schema.rb` will now be updated with the new table because Rails automatically tries to sync your database with the `schema.rb` file everytime you run a DB command. Now, uncomment the migration change and push your changes for other developers to get the table.

Comment: I don't want to drop the table.

Comment: We even don’t have `schema.db` file in our project.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin solution works, but will probably lead to DB inconsistency between author and other project devs. Moreover, there is no guarantee that block `do ... end` works. So Lenin is right: DB schema should be managed via migrations. Existing data can be repopulated via _seeds_ or _rake_ tasks.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Don't agree with each sentence. Also, none of the sentences disprove DB inconsistency or wrong `do ... end` block.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Beside the fact Rails is far from ideal, _"many companies who ..."_ is not an argument (just because _"companies ... modern ... are *using* schema.rb"_ >> _"... who dropped one"_). But that two issues are the real.

Comment: The official Rails guides still state: "The `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql` is a snapshot of the current state of your database and is the authoritative source for rebuilding that database."